# Merge array and hash in ruby if key appears in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays `one = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `two = [{1=>'10'},{3=>'22'},{7=>'40'}]`

Two will have `one.length` hashes or less. I want a new array of values from two if it's key appears in one, if not then use 0.
The new array would be `[10,0,22,0,0,0,40]`
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your `two` is invalid.

Comment: That is also invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it using [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
two.reduce({}, :merge).values_at(*one).map(&:to_i)
# => [10, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 40]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
h = [{1 => '10'}, {3 => '22'}, {7 => '40'}].inject(:merge).to_h
one.map{|e| h[e].to_i}
# => [10, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 40]
```

Comment: You should pass an empty hash as the first argument to `inject`, otherwise `[].inject(:merge) # => nil` and `h[e]` would raise a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: @toro2k Your point is correct, but I would rather do `to_h`. That looks prettier to me.

Comment: @sawa we can combine 2 answers 

two.inject(:merge).values_at(*one).map(&:to_i)